# How to estimate a focal sum

Tags: google-earth-engine

hope your are fine!
I am trying to estimate a kernel circle with a focal function summing the raster values, but just found hat there is no `image.focal_sum()` as I expected.
Instead I found the focal_*: max, min, mean, median and mode, estimates.
Is there a reason for not having te sum function?
How would be possible to get this estimate?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the "image.reduceNeighborhood()" option, see here (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reducers_reduce_neighborhood)

```
// Compute sum over round kernel
var result = imgage.reduceNeighborhood({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  kernel: ee.Kernel.circle(7),
});
```